# Xsl fo image from filepath using fo.net

Tags: xsl-fo, filepath

I am trying to load an image into the header for my pdf document which is generated using fo.net.

For some reason I cannot get XSL to pick up the correct filepath, I have verified the image is present, code is:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
  <fo:block padding-top="1cm" margin-left="1cm">
    <fo:external-graphic src="url('C:\\Projects\\Reports\\frontbanner960_2.jpg')" />
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\\Projects\\Reports\\frontbanner960_2.jpg` is not a proper URL.

Try `file:///C:/Projects/Reports/frontbanner960_2.jpg` instead.

Comment: @Haroon: For the record, `src="C:/s/Logo.png"` is not a correct image reference according to the XSL specification. FO.NET is based on a very old version (0.20.4) of FOP which apparently allows this non-standard syntax.